# filling between lines with plus sign

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to fill between any curves with + sign in matlab. For simplicity, you can consider the unit square and I want to have + signs everywhere inside of the square. I have tried to use fill function in matlab, but that's make the region colorful but not filled with + sign. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to use the `stipple` function from Chad Greene's [Climate Data Toolbox](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/70338-climate-data-toolbox-for-matlab) from Matlab file exchange. You can read the docs on the function [here](http://www.chadagreene.com/CDT/stipple_documentation.html).

```
xx=[-10:.01:10];
yy=[-10:.01:10];
[X,Y]=ndgrid(xx,yy);
mask=zeros(size(X));
mask(X>0 & Y>0)=1;
figure
pcolor(X,Y,mask),shading flat,colorbar
hold on
stipple(X,Y,logical(mask),'density',35,'color','r','marker','+','markersize',9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a double for loop to do it manual. ie. i wrote a code for you;

```
t=0:0.1:10;
y=5+5*sin(2*pi*t/10);
filler=zeros(10,10); 
plot(t,y);
hold on 
for a=1:10
    for b=1:10
        if a<5+5*sin(2*pi*b/10)
            filler(a,b)=1;
            scatter(b,a,'+','MarkerEdgeColor',[0 .7 .7])

        end
    end
end
```

Yuo can change the density of '+' signs with by multiplaction a constant with a and b. Hope it works for you.

If you have 2 curves to fill gap between, just add this command to if statement.

```
&& a>(Function of curve 2)
```

Comment: Nice! This would be more performant though if you collected all the coordinates first and then did a single call to `scatter`. Having one or 100 graphics objects is a bug difference. And then with `meshgrid` you could get rid of the loop as well.